# How to disable "Slow Motion" function in QuickTime Player control panel

Tags: video, quicktime

I found that when I use QuickTime Player to play videos, it shows different control panels. Sometimes it shows the normal one like this:

[image]

I can click the time and change it to frame.
For some reasons, it may display control panels like this:

[image]

There is a controller to enable the edit of slow motion. And in this mode, it is impossible to click the time and display frame number.
I tested with the same format videos (MP4), and it seems which control panel it displays is kind of random.
I was wondering how can I manually enable or disable the "slow motion" bar.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the slow motion controller always shows up when the frame rate of the mp4 is 120 frames per second.

If you change the frame rate of the videos with ffmpeg, there are other instances where the bars show up that I don't remember specifically.

Comment: Can you give some more information to improve the quality of your answer?